# css single or multiple line vertical align

Tags: html, css

I have a title that can have one or more lines.

How can I align the text vertically? If it was always one line I could just set the line-height to the container height.

I can do it using JavaScript, but I don't really like it, I'm searching for a pure CSS way.

Also if the container could expand with the lines it would be perfect, so I can always have the same padding on the top and bottom.

[image]

Comment: In case the container height can change... then how about this? http://jsbin.com/idiqih/edit#preview

Answer (score 114, accepted):

For this you can use `display:table-cell` property:

```css
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}
.wrap {
  display: table;
  height:  100px;
  width:   160px;
  padding: 10px;
  border:  thin solid darkgray;
}
.wrap p {
  display:        table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>Example of single line.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inline">
  <div class="wrap">
    <p>To look best, text should really be centered inside.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it works IE8 & above. Read this article for more info: [*CSS Tricks: Vertically Center Multi-Lined Text*](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/).

Comment: I wanted exactly the same thing, but also needed that the div should consume entire height available. This should help for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/260665

Comment: If you don;t want the `.wrap` to have *magic numbers* for the `height` and `width`, you can set each of them to `100%`. Then apply the `width` and `height` to the parent of the `.wrap` elements.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't like the `display:table` trick (I know I don't) here's a solution without it:

```
.cen {
  min-height:5em; width:12em; background:red; margin:1em 0;
}
.cen p {
  display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0 0 0 1em; width:10em;
}
.cen::after {
   display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; line-height:5em;
   width:0; content:"\00A0"; overflow:hidden;
}
```

with HTML

```
<div class="cen">
 <p>Text in div 1</p>
</div>
```

This gives the div a height of 5em, unless the content is heigher, then it grows.
Live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4nhMT/46/).

Edit: Oh, which browsers is this supposed to work on? IE8 won't cooperate.

(Later edit: updated CSS to handle issues in Chrome)

Comment: Cool technique. One issue I ran into was when the text in the box wrapped on its own (instead of with the `<br>` tags shown in the example) I wound up with a good deal of extra white space at the bottom of each element in Chrome. It seems like the pseudo element is wrapping onto a new line. Any idea how to mitigate that?

Comment: @DominicP You're right. Apparently the `::after` block thinks it does have a width (because of its content), so it won't fit after the `p`. Unfortunately it does need the content, or it would collapse altogether and it wouldn't work. But I'm not sure why it does this only with wrapping lines and not with single-line `p`s.

Comment: Anyway, I updated the answer with the solution. The trick is to make the `p` less wide than the div, so there's room to the right of it for the zero-width `::after` block. Hope this helps!

Comment: If accessibility is a concern, this is the correct answer. You shouldn't classify a `<div>` as a `table-item`, it will confuse the screen reader and, of course, the user.

Answer (score 9):

I really like this solution:

```
<div>
    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height: --The height of your box here--"></span>
    <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Put your multi-line content here</span>
</div>
```

Feel free to use stylesheets, and 100% for the height...

Also might have to comment out spaces between the span tags, since these are inline-blocks

Credit goes to [Hades](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285470/hades). I got it from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443712/how-to-vertical-align-text-that-runs-multiple-lines)

```html
<div style="outline:thin solid red;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height: 60px;"></span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Put your multi-line content here.</span>
</div>

<div style="outline:thin solid red;">
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; height: 60px;"></span>
  <span style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">Put your multi-line content here. Put your multi-line content here. Put your multi-line content here. Put your multi-line content here. Put your multi-line content here.</span>
</div>
```

**Note:** This appears not to work with multiple line content.

Comment: This is an awesome solution :) thank you! I hate having the rely on tables!

Comment: I can't believe this worked! By far the only solution that worked!

Comment: This is the cleanest solution to my taste. I wonder if CSS specs will provide a non-hacky way of doing it in my lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `vertical-align: center` and `display: table-cell`, you might want to take a look at the newer method called **CSS display flex** which is MUCH simpler

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px; 
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    
    /* Only add these 2 lines */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipsum dolor</div>
```

Comment: works great but hard to limit it to number of lines, it overflows

Comment: Best answer for new browsers! Thanks for adding this new flex solution to the old question.

Answer (score 3):

somthing like this

## HTML

```
<div>
    <p>
       Lorem Ipsum is simply
    </p>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
div {
   display: table;
}
p {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If You want your text to be responsive, wrapping words from one to multiple lines as width is dynamically changing, mentioned above trick with `inline-block` helper (which have the best compability here) can be not sufficient, as `.inlinehelper` can push wrapping text down under itself.
 Here's complete solution for such a simpel task:

*HTML:*

```
<div id="responsive_wrap">
    <span class="inlinehelper"><span id="content">        
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#responsive_wrap {   
   display: block;    
   height: 100%; //dimensions just for   
   width: 100%;  //example's sake
   white-space: nowrap;
}

#content {   
   display: inline-block;        
   white-space: initial;
}

.inlinehelper {
   height: 100%;    
   width: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

**Notice** the `white-space:nowrap` property, which prevents `.inlinehelper` and `#content` to wrap in relation to each other.
`white-space:initial` on `#content` resets ability to wrap for `span` itself;

**Another Option:**
More a matter of personal preference. You can use a pseudo element instead of `.inlinehelper`. Remove the `.inlinehelper` css rules and element and add this pseudo-element css selector:

```
#responsive_wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
}
```

P.S.: I figured out that this is really old question too late, therefore let this answer be, maybe it will be helpfull for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Styling wise, a table would be the best way to layout your content (put the style tags in CSS):

```
<table style="border:1;collapse;width:300px;padding:5px;background-color:red;">
<tr>
    <td style="width:250px;vertical-align:middle;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ipswum dolor</td>
    <td style="width:50px;vertical-align:top;color:white;">1 Line</td>
</tr>
```

Line count will require a JS script, have a look here:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-44333.html

Answer (score 0):

I like that kind of solution. I saw somewhere this trick in stackoverflow but do not remember where exactly. Very usefel! :)

```css
ul {
background: #000; 
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #F7F7F7;
}
ul li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}
ul li:after {
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  font-size: 40px;
  content: ">";
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -24px;
  color: #FFDA00;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s all ease;
  transition: 0.25s all ease;
}
ul li a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 38px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: " ";
  height: 100%;
}
ul li a span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="dn">
  <a href="kapec.ru.php"><span> Lorem ipsum 1 LINE</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="varianti.ru.php"><span>Lorem ipsum <br> 2 lines </span></a>
  </li>

 </ul>
```