# CSS image text overlay to center of image and Image box shadow oddity

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get text to align to the exact center of an image.
I've looked at w3schools example and a few others and can't get them to work.

Another issue I'm having is getting the image in the container to fill the whole container. It does this without the box shadow but as soon as I put a box shadow on it fills up only most of the container.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPMC87/nztcg4u2/

```
                     <div id="image">
                        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
                            <p id="image-text">
                              Hello World!</p> 
                            </div>
```

Comment: Single line of text [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/z2mxtpfe/)? There are millions of questions about this. You could just place the properties on the `<a>` itself as well, no need for the `<p>`.

Comment: @misterManSam That's it exactly. Sorry if it's been asked a lot I tried a few other people's answers and it didn't work. Thanks a million!

Comment: How do I mark your answer as the answer?

Comment: Bear in mind that if the text goes over more than one line it will break with this technique. Don't worry about marking an answer (it's optional anyway), the question will get closed as a duplicate :)

Comment: @misterManSam ok great, thank you! If I do want to add more than one line would I have to make a new div and change it's line height or is there a better way?

Comment: There are a bunch of question [like this one here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9192389/2930477) that address this. Keywords to look for are "Vertical Align" and "Multiple Lines"

Comment: @misterManSam Cool, I'll have a look. You've been a great help. Thank you :)

Comment: No worries :) [This example is one of my favourite techniques](http://jsfiddle.net/by6h4z1u/). There is a good write up of how it works [over here on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). It uses a "Ghost element"

Comment: @misterManSam I was just looking at vertical-align:middle; Can't believe I never knew of it's existence haha. Very good technique in that fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

change the `max-width` property to `100%` in the `#image` css

```
#image {
   max-width:100%;
}
```

let me know what you exactly want in center alignment.

Because according to me it is already center aligned
whether you want `horizontal` or `vertical` center alignment

Comment: I want it both but think the two guys have covered that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hjqe3cej/

I've made some changes to your code, mainly:

```
/* fill entire DIV element with your image */    
background-size: cover;
```

And for the `<p>` element:

```
/* absolute positioning required for this to work */
position: absolute;
/* start the <p> element half-way from the top of your container */
top: 50%;
/* make sure it's flush to the left so that your text is in the center, horisontally */
left: 0;

/* to be as accurate as possible, you should know what would be the height of your text block */
height: 20px;
/* and then subtract half of it to ensure your text is dead center vertically */
margin-top: -10px;
```

Also, make sure that you are using HTML5 to code this page as HTML4 standards do not allow block elements inside of `<a>`

Comment: ...I assumed you wanted to center it vertically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Below pattern will short help you out.

```
#image a{
display:table-cell;
max-height:100%;
max-width:100%;
height:500px;
width:500px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

To see live demo click here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Salehin/nztcg4u2/4/